# javascript regex to get url from string containing script tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to figure out how to write a regex that would provide the url from a string like this:

```
'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://chrismills.la/test.js"></script>';
```

This works, but I need to find a cleaner way to do this:

```
var url = '';
_content.replace(/src ?= ?"([^"]+)"/gi, function(res) {
    url = res;
    url = url.replace('src=','');
    url = url.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
    url = url.replace(/["']+/g, '')
});
script.src = url;
```

In action:
http://jsfiddle.net/zb3jh180/

SOLUTION, based on answer below:

```
var regex = /<script.*?src="(.*?)"/gmi;
var url = regex.exec(_content);
script.src = url[1];
```

Comment: Do you have access to the DOM object? Reading the `src` attribute directly would be easier if you do.

Comment: You [shouldn't use regexp for that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/36866)... No... `/https?:\/\/[^"]*/`

Comment: No access to the DOM in this case, the scripts are added dynamically with js

Comment: What? What is added to the page? If you want to get the src for every script on the current page you can use something like `for(var i=0, len=document.scripts.length; i < len; ++i) {console.log(document.scripts[i].src)}`

Comment: scripts are added as strings from js or an external js file as clearly shown in the code/jsfiddle.  It has been answered already.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
<script.*?src="(.*?)"
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/zN6lC6/5)**

Or also something like:

```
<script.*?"(http.*?)"
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/zN6lC6/4)**

Comment: This one here is more stable and does not return false positives like <script></script><img src="not-wanted.jpg"/>: ```/<script[a-z1-9"'\/ =]*?src="(.*?)"/gmi```

Comment: @Andreas How could this be altered to allow for single quotes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Updated the fiddle, let me know if this was what you are going for. Basically just creating a capture group:

```
            var srcRegEx = /src="(.*?)"/g;
            var source = srcRegEx.exec(_content);
            script.src = source[1];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zb3jh180/1/

Comment: Try it on a string like this: `<tag src="link1" alt="text">Oh, "SNAP"!</tag>` and you see how it fails... it's too greedy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a string of script tags containing "http://chrismills.la" in the src attribute, you can use this Regex:

```
<script.*?src="(http:\/\/chrismills\.la.*?)"*<\/script>
```